# Autofac: register component as different services using different constructors

Tags: c#, autofac

I would like to register a singleton component for multiple services and define which constructor to use, depending on which service was used during the resolve call.

I tried this:

```
_builder.RegisterType<TComponent>()
    .As<IService1>()
    .FindConstructorsWith(ConstructorFinder1)
    .SingleInstance();

_builder.RegisterType<TComponent>()
    .As<IService2>()
    .FindConstructorsWith(ConstructorFinder2)
    .SingleInstance();
```

But this leads to two different "singleton" instances, depending on which service was used.

So I tried:

```
_builder.RegisterType<TComponent>()
    .As<IService1>()
    .FindConstructorsWith(ConstructorFinder1)
    .As<IService2>()
    .FindConstructorsWith(ConstructorFinder2)
    .SingleInstance();
```

This solves the singleton issue, but sadly the second `FindConstructorsWith` call overrides the first call, i.e. for both services `ConstructorFinder2` is used.

I had assumed (hoped) that the ConstructorFinders would be stored with respect to the service, but apparently this is not the case.

Is what I'm trying to achieve conceptually wrong, does Autofac not support it or am I simply missing something?

**EDIT:**
Once again thanks to Travis for his great response. Apparently I left out a few details that made things confusing. Let me add some now.

This question was actually a kind of follow-up to [How to determine which constructor Autofac uses when resolving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533374/how-to-determine-which-constructor-autofac-uses-when-resolving) (where Travis also helped me along). So the issue comes up when deserializing and it affects many different objects.

I get the arguments about composition, seperation of concerns and how having several ctors is often considered a code smell, but in the context of deserialization (at least for the app I'm currently developing) it is extremely useful to be able to create instances differently, depending on if they are newly built or deserialized from a project file. Several members that need to be initialized when building a new instance do not have to be initialized when deserializing (because their values would be overridden during deserialization anyway). It would mean extra performance costs and (and, in this case) cause other issues regarding the throw-away-initializations.

After spending days trying to find a solution (with complications also coming from the Newtonsoft Json side) I've decided to discontinue Autofac and implement our own IOC container. For general purposes it cannot (obviously!) compete with Autofac in any way, but since we were really only using a small subset of Autofac's great features, I felt we could try to roll our own. It took me a lot less than the days I've spent on trying to wrap my head around a monolithic black box. Yes, Autofac is open source, but stepping through the code no walk in the park.

First tests are very promising and it feels good to regain full control of such a vital component of the application.

Again, the reason for leaving Autofac was that it is not (feasibly) possible to define how a singleton component is constructed depending on the service it was constructed for. And from a general structure/concept point-of-view I understand that it makes sense to strictly seperate the service and the construction-how-tos. But during deserializing things are different, I believe. And, now that I'm independent of Autofac, I may decide to alter the mechanisms so they fit into the overall concept in a more straight-forward way.

Comment: You won't be able to have two *different* constructors called and get back one singleton instance, each invocation of the constructor is going to give you a different instance which is why your first example results in two different singletons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sort of a difficult question to answer because it seems you have some underlying goal you're trying to achieve and you have a solution you want to work but perhaps it's the wrong solution and you should ask a [new] question depending on how this response works out for you.

Let me walk this through to see if I can explain why it's hard to answer.

> I would like to register a singleton component for multiple services and define which constructor to use, depending on which service was used during the resolve call.

If it's a *singleton* that means there's *one in the whole system*, right? It'll be effectively "first in wins." If something resolves it as an `IService1` then the constructor associated with that will be called and even if you try resolving it as `IService2` later no construction will happen because the singleton was created. The converse is also true - `IService2` gets resolved and the constructor path is followed there, then things asking for `IService1` will get the singleton and no constructor is called.

That raises a concern:

- If you *know* which thing, for sure, will be resolving first, then why do you need two different constructor selectors?
- If you *don't know* which thing will be resolving first, then are you accounting for the system unpredictability?

I have seen these sorts of questions before and *usually* what they indicate is one of two things:

1. You are trying to do some sort of selection or special logic based on context. [There's an Autofac FAQ about this that may help.](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html) Usually the way around this is to refactor. I'll get back to that in a second.
2. You are trying to "share registrations" between two different applications. The answer to this is to [use Autofac modules and reuse those](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/modules.html); but if there are special registrations for each app type, let that happen.

This isn't to say that either of these are what you're asking for, but this is where I've seen such questions. Usually there's some unspoken goal where a solution has been pre-chosen and it's better ask how to solve the goal rather than how to implement a very specific solution. Again, I could be wrong.

On the refactoring note for item 1, above, I can further guess based on the desire for a singleton that there's some sort of resource like a database connection that needs to be shared or is expensive to spin up. Consider splitting the `TComponent` into three separate classes:

- `TCommonExpensiveComponent` - this is the stuff that is actually expensive to spin up and really does need to be a singleton, but does not differ across `IService1` and `IService2`.
- `TService1` - implement `IService1` with only the required constructor so you don't need a constructor finder. Have it consume `TCommonExpensiveComponent`.
- `TService2` - implement `IService2` with only the required constructor so you don't need a constructor finder. Have it consume `TCommonExpensiveComponent`.

The idea being avoid the complexity of registrations, keep the shared/singleton that you want, and still get different constructor usage as needed. You may want to throw in some common base/abstract class, too, that the `TService` classes can derive from if there's really a lot of common logic.

> Is what I'm trying to achieve conceptually wrong, does Autofac not support it or am I simply missing something?

Technically you could do some really crazy stuff in Autofac if you wanted to, like write a custom [registration source](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/registration-sources.html) that waits for someone to query for the `IService1` or `IService2` registration and then picks a constructor based on that, dynamically serving the registration as needed. **But, truly, don't even start down this road.**

Instead, it would be good to clarify what the problem is that you're trying to solve and how you plan on working around the challenges listed above if my response here doesn't help. **Do that in a brand new question that goes into more detail about your challenge and what you've tried.** This not being a forum, having a conversation to try and weed out additional help given the current question really isn't feasible. Plus, taking a second to step back and maybe reframe the question sounds like it might help here.